# Highcharts.dateFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", this.x) not working

Tags: highcharts

this chart (line) works perfectly. But I have a format issue with the dateFormat(): I cannot display the times in Y-m-d H-M-S format.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#chart").highcharts({
                    xAxis: {
                        type: "datetime",
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat("%I:%M", this.value);
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: [{
                        labels: {
                            formatter:  function()  { return (this.value) },
                        }
                    }],
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            var s = "<span>" + Highcharts.dateFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", this.x)  +  "</span>";
                                s += "<table>",
                                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                                s += '<tr><td><span>' + point.series.name + "</span> :</td><td></strong>" + point.y + "</strong></td></tr>";
                            });
                            s += "</table>"
                            return s;
                        },
                        shared: true,
                        style:  {
                            "line-height":  "120%"
                        },
                        useHTML:  true
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: '1',
                        data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
                    }, {
                        name: '2',
                        data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
                    }, {
                        name: '3',
                        data: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
                    }],
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`

why tooltip give me 1970-01-01 00
when it should give me 2016-02-05 02:00
what is wrong whit this code
and xAxis give me 00:00:00.0002 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add xAxis information, just add pointStart (to set up a starting point) and pointInterval (interval between X data).

Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/5mdmgmLL/)

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 01, 5,2),
    pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 // one Hour
  }
},
```